# how to save inputs to file and call the inputs later (after closing app)

Tags: java, methods, input, save, call

guys iam new to java so please help me 
iam making a simple app of exam app  which that the teacher can input the Questions
and save it 
when the student open the app they will be asked if they are students then the 
app will start the Questions 
i made 2 files  Teacher file and Student file 
here is the code

```
package com.belal.teacher;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Teacher {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

    // 1 is the Q
    // 2 choice 1
    // 3 choice 2
    // 4 choice 3
    // 5 correct choice 
    // 6 grade of the Q




    String userinput1;
    String userinput2;
    String userinput3;
    String userinput4;
    String userinput5;
    String userinput6;



    Scanner input1 =  new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner input2 =  new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner input3 =  new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner input4 =  new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner input5 =  new Scanner(System.in);           
    Scanner input6 =  new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println(" enter the question: ");
        userinput1 = input1.nextLine();
    System.out.println(" enter  answer 1 : ");
        userinput2 = input2.nextLine();
    System.out.println(" enter  answer 2 : " );
        userinput3 = input3.nextLine();
    System.out.println(" enter  answer 3 : " );
        userinput4 = input4.nextLine();
    System.out.println(" enter the correct answer : " );
        userinput5 = input5.nextLine();
    System.out.println("enter the grade of this Q : ");
        userinput6 = input6.nextLine();


        }
}
```

i want to call the input methods from this class under else i want to call the inputs from there under Else

```
package com.belal.student;

import java.util.Scanner;
import com.belal.teacher.Teacher;

public class Student {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(" type (a) if u are a student type (b) if u are a teacher");
        Scanner input =  new Scanner(System.in);
        input.nextLine();



        if (input != input ) {
            Teacher.main(args);

        }else {
            System.out.println();



        }
    }

}
```

Comment: you need to store questions in a  db

Comment: You need to store data in a databse or a textfile .

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to understand exactly what you're trying to do. At a minimum, it seems like you're trying to read/write to a database. If this is just for learning purposes and the read/write part isn't the main focus, you could just read/write to a text file. (Though if this is ever supposed to be multi-threaded that's a shoddy solution). Here's some code I wrote a while back for quick 'n' dirty reading/writing text.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TextIO {

/** Write a string to a text file at the given directory.
 * @param f - directory, a string
 * @param s - text to write
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static void write(String f, String s) throws IOException {
    write(new File(f), s);
}

/** Write a string to a text file at the given directory.
 * @param f - directory, a file
 * @param s - text to write
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static void write(File f, String s) throws IOException {
    FileWriter fr= new FileWriter(f);
    BufferedWriter br= new BufferedWriter(fr);

    br.write(s);

    br.flush();
    br.close();
}

/** Reads File f as a text file.
 * @param f - the File to read
 * @return - a String[], each entry of which is a line of text in f
 * @throws IOException - if the file reading goes bad.
 */
public static String[] read(File f) throws IOException {
    FileReader fr = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        fr = new FileReader(f);
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();

    while(br.ready()){
        s.add(br.readLine());
    }

    br.close();
    String[] sArray = new String[s.size()];
    sArray = s.toArray(sArray);
    return sArray;
}

}
```

If you want more specific help beyond this, try to break your question up into discrete tasks you're trying to accomplish.